# Is it possible to override yarn install to use https instead of git

Tags: npm-install, yarnpkg

I have following dependency in `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "vue-particles": "github:creotip/vue-particles"
  }
```

`yarn install` is failing as I do not have `ssh` keys setup where I was running the command.
Is it possible for me to force it use `https` instead of `git/ssh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to override url using fillowing command

```
git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf ssh://git@github
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```